# Adjusted my PYCHARM IDE heap size memory to too high a value, Since then the IDE wont OPEN

Tags: python, pycharm, ide, heap-memory

So, I happened to be coding using pycharm IDE 2023. Got a pop up dialogue box "Low Maximum Heap Size Memory" Click to adjust, which i did. However, i input the highest possible value i could think of, i,e 9999999. Since then my PYCHARM IDE wont open. i have tried uninstalling it, intstalling an older version to no avail, Could anyone on here assist me with a solution?????

I adjusted my heap size memory for my IDE expecting the IDE to probably run code quicker, intuitively.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.